# mongodb mapreduce finalize function isn't working from javascript (same code is working from shell)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, shell, mapreduce

I have the following strange situation. I've started writing map/reduce jobs for MongoDB. I now have code (see Map/Reduce/Finalize functions in code below) that is working, except for the "finalize" step. The same code, ran through the mongo shell is producing the expected results (file_count field is added to the result, based upon arraylength. Both JS and Shell command populate the files_per_disc collection equally (files array, per disc, contains the same results). I already tried setting jsMode to true/false.

Any help / Suggestions?

Thanks!!

Sander

```
var mongojs = require('mongojs');

var db = mongojs('mongodb://super.local/sha', ['files', 'files_per_disc']);

db.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('database error', err)
})

db.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('database connected')
})

var files_per_disc = {};

files_per_disc.execute = function() {
    console.log('execute');

    var mapper = function() {
        var key = this.disc; // Disc
        var mapObject = {
            files: [this.filename]
        };
        if (this.filesize > 5000000000) {
            emit(key, mapObject);
        }
    };

    var reducer = function(key, values) {
        var reducedObject = {
            files: []
        };
        values.forEach(function(value) {
            value.files.forEach(function(item) {
                if (reducedObject.files.indexOf(item) == -1) {
                    reducedObject.files.push(item);
                }
            });
        });
        return reducedObject;
    };

    var finalizer = function(key, reducedObject) {
        if (reducedObject.files) {
            reducedObject.file_count = reducedObject.files.length;
        }
        return reducedObject;
    };

    db.files.mapReduce(
        mapper,
        reducer, {
            jsMode: false,
            out: 'files_per_disc',
            finalize: finalizer
        },
        function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err)
            };
            return console.log(result);
        }
    );
};

module.exports = files_per_disc;
```

Comment: Hmmmmm... Dug a little deeper. It a problem that is related to the "mongojs" package. After "refactoring" my code to use the "mongodb" NPM package, it IS working........ I opened a github issue [link](https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs/issues/264)